# $.when(...).then(...).finally is not a function

Tags: jquery

Error:

> $.when(...).then(...).finally is not a function

My code:

```
$.when($.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" )).then(function () {
    swal('success')
}).finally(function () {
    // Reset form elements
});
```

I want to reset my form after these two API call done.

Comment: `$.when()` returns a [`Deferred` object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Those have no `.finally()` method.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution. The `$.when` hasn't finally method.

Refrence link: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

And It has two callback arguments. Like below,

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

So my code is like the below.

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).then(function () {
    swal('success');
    // Reset form elements
}, function () {
    // Reset form elements
});
```